# How to use recursion in python to parse method body from java code?

Tags: java, python, regex, parsing

I have a java code and i need to parse it in python.I am using regex in python for this purpose. I was successfully able to find method names , but to find method body i need to write regular expression with conditions.
for ex. code i was parsing?

```
class abc
{
 public void main()
 {
     //some code

      if(blabla)
      {

      }
      else
      {

       }
       //some code

   }
public static int method1(int asd,int bad)
{
    //body
}

}
```

I need output as [(int,method1,"body"),('void',main,"body")]
So I wrote regular expression like 
`r'[public|private|protected]\s+[static]\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\(.*\)\n\{'` 
to find method name ,but how to find body as it may contain several `'{','}'`?

Comment: regular expressions aren't the appropriate tool for this job.

*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems."* -- Jamie Zawinski

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't going to be successful with regular expressions. What you need is an actual parser.

The parser I would recommend is [`pyparsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/), it is easy to use and understand.

If you need more expressive parsing there is always `ANTLR` which has grammars for Java already built and outputs python code easily.

Comment: but is there any regx to support this like recursion or condition based regx?

Comment: What part of *you aren't going to be successful with regular expressions, you need an actual parser* isn't clear?